# Is it possible to retrieve the best-selling products of any Shopify store in JSON format?

Tags: shopify, product

I was able to access the Shopify page view with the **best-selling filter** applied by using this URL:

```
{shop_name}.myshopify.com/collections/all?&sort_by=best-selling
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to retrieve the best-selling products of any Shopify store in JSON format.

I did find a way to retrieve a store's products in JSON format by using this URL:

```
{shop_name}.myshopify.com/products.json
```

Can anyone tell me how I can apply the **best-selling filter** to the products.json URL?

I attempted to apply a filter using the following URL:

```
{shop_name}.myshopify.com/products.json?sort_by=best-selling
```

but unfortunately, it was unsuccessful.